# Why is "ADD_YEARS" an invalid identifier?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use SQL's "ADD_YEARS" in an Oracle PLSQL Procedure.

However, (assuming it's actually to blame) it has an error on compilation: "invalid identifier".

I suspect that this is because the ADD_YEARS is something out of SQL, and not PLSQL. They don't seem to like each other. The only way I can think of doing this is to create a local variable and assign it the result I'd normally have gotten from ADD_YEARS. However, when I tried I couldn't figure out how to actually...assign some value to that. There's SELECT INTO but that makes 0 sense in this case.

```
-- If in good standing, extend membership 1 year. 
-- If not but within grace (6 months), extend to 1 year from today.
-- Otherwise, explain renewal involves penalty. If no ID, print message.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE renew(id1 IN member.id%type) IS
    temp1 member.expr_date%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT expr_date INTO temp1 FROM member WHERE id = id1;

    IF temp1 > CURRENT_DATE THEN
        UPDATE member
        SET expr_date = ADD_YEARS(expr_date, 1)
        WHERE id = id1;
    ELSIF ADD_MONTHS(temp1, 6) > CURRENT_DATE THEN
        UPDATE member
        SET expr_date = ADD_YEARS(CURRENT_DATE, 1)
        WHERE id = id1;
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('Renewal will incur a penalty!');
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('That ID does not exist as a member!');
END;
/
show errors
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Errors for PROCEDURE RENEW:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
7/3  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
8/19     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ADD_YEARS": invalid identifier
11/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
12/19    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ADD_YEARS": invalid identifier
```

Thanks much for any help! I'm still very new to SQL and PL/SQL. Getting over some of its quirks has been difficult.

Comment: Replace `ADD_YEARS(CURRENT_DATE, 1)` with `ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, 12)` since in oracle there is nothing called  `ADD_YEARS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, you cannot use `ADD_YEARS` since in Oracle nothing exist as `ADD_YEARS`. You can inturn use `ADD_MONTHS` or  `INTERVAL` clause.

So you can modify  your block update statement as :

> SET expr_date = ADD_YEARS(expr_date, 1)

```
1)  SET expr_date = ADD_MONTHS(expr_date, 12)
```

Or

```
2) SET expr_date = expr_date + interval '1' YEAR
```

Comment: Wow. I  could have *sworn* I tested ADD_YEARS earlier and it worked. I'm really sorry, I feel like a doofus now. Thanks for the assistance.